# Expressions are not allowed at the top level when writing in ContentView.swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

While making a chart I need to create the date formatters. The code throws an error of "Expressions are not allowed at the top level" when writing it in ContentView.swift.

```
let dmmmyyyyDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dmmmyyyyDateFormatter.dateFormat = "d MMM yyyy" //Expressions are not...
let dmmmDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dmmmDateFormatter.dateFormat = "d MMM" //Expressions are not...
```

Should it be inside of a function? If so what should it return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are trying to place this code inside the `struct MyView...`, the error message tells you what your problem is. You can't have  expressions ("code") at that level.  You can only have property declarations.

You can achieve what you want by using a closure;

```
let dmmmyyyyDateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.dateFormat = "d MMM yyyy"
    return df
}()
```

This executes the closure (which returns the object you are after) and assigns it to the property.  Since the expressions are hidden are inside the closure, the compiler is happy as it has a context for executing the code.